# How to convert pandas Timedelta into datetime?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a python dataframe.One of its column is  like Timedelta('0 days 09:35:00').If I save it into mysql, the time is changed to 34500000000000.

How can I properly save the time into mysql?

Comment: What is "properly"?

Comment: A timedelta is not a date or time or timestamp, it's a difference - basically a number of seconds - between two datetimes. Anything that can represent a (possibly very long) integer should do.

Comment: Timedelta and datetime are two different things. This is like asking "How to convert distance to geo location". A time delta is difference between two timestamps. Without knowing at least one of those timestamps you can't know either of them.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define an appropriate format to store your `timdelta` object in mysql. The reason is that the timedelta format type does not exists in mysql as far as I'm aware. For example, if you want to convert the timedelta object in seconds or days as float:

```
timedelta.total_seconds() 
timedelta.days
```

If you want to convert the timedelta to string:

```
str(timedelta)
```